# Writing to mysql with prepared statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prepared-statement

I am trying to use function in vb.net to build a prepared statement to save to a mysql db, but using the examples provided with the .net connector for mysql, I'm struggling to get it to work.

My function looks like this...

```vb
Public Function TestSQLUpdate(ByVal link_id As String, ByRef updatetext As String, ByRef entrytype As String)
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    conn.ConnectionString = main.connection_string
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO case_updates VALUES(@lid, @updatext, @entrytype, @user)"
        cmd.Prepare()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lid", lid)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updatetxt", updatetext)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrytype", entrytype)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", main.activeuser)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.Number & " has occurred: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

I'm running this as a test, but get the error:

> Column count doesnt match value count at row 1

I have the same number of parameters as i do fields, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Sorry if this is a dumb question; they're only easy when you know the answer! :)

Comment: `@updatext` <> `@updatetxt`  You should also be disposing of all the things there which have a `Dispose()` method.  Use a `Using` block and `AddWithValue` is suboptimal - it leaves the Provider to guess at the datatype

Comment: [**Please don't put tags in the title**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: @plutonix apologies, that was a spelling error when writing my post here. I change my variable names sometimes when posting to not reveal certain parts of the db structure.

What is the optimal alternative to addwithvalue?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@updatetxt", MySQLDbType.String).Value = updatetext` using whatever DbType is appropriate

Comment: Option Strict is also strongly advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not the result of the parameter count not matching the number of the supplied parameters.

In your insert statement you did not specify which columns you would like to insert values into, therefore mysql expects you to provide values for all columns in the table. `case_updates` table has more than 4 columns, hence the error message. Either you need to supply values to all columns in the table in the `values()` clause or you need to list the columns you would like to insert into.

```
INSERT INTO case_updates(lid, updatetext, entrytype, `user`) ...
```

(assuming your field names match your parameter names)